# javascript update object key/value based on another object by mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am looping over some object and updating the values of another based on some lookups, currently I have problems with getting the correct values in the mapping.

```
let users = [
  {
    "id": "123",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com",
    "name": " John Doe",
    "group": "1",
    "subgroup": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "email": "tom.hans@stk.com",
    "name": " Tom hans",
    "group": "2",
    "subgroup": "1"
  }
];

let groupData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Stars",
    subgroup: [
        {
          id: "1",
          pseudo: "big"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          pseudo: "small"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Stones",
    subgroup: [
        {
          id: "1",
          pseudo: "tiny"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          pseudo: "huge"
        }
      ]
  }
];

const allUsers = {};
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    let groupID = users[i].group,
        subgroupID = users[i].subgroup;

    users[i].group = users[i].group ? groupData[groupID][name] : '';
    users[i].subgroup = users[i].subgroup ?
        groupData[groupID].subgroup[subgroupID][name] : '';

    allUsers[users[i].id] = users[i];
}
```

The result of `allUsers` will look like:

```
{
  123: {
    "id": "123",
    "email": "john.doe@acme.com",
    "name": " John Doe",
    "group": "Stars",
    "subgroup": "big"
  },
  456: {
    "id": "456",
    "email": "tom.hans@stk.com",
    "name": " Tom hans",
    "group": "Stones",
    "subgroup": "tiny"
  }
};
```

Currently, I have lookup problems inside my `for loop` to get the name of the group/subgroup.

Could somebody help to fix this issue? preferably with ecma6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using groupData as if it's keys where the groupID. However, it's an array. You should try to use it's find method:

```
const allUsers = {};
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    let groupID = users[i].group,
        subgroupID = users[i].subgroup;
    let userGroup = groupData.find(group => group.id === groupID);

    users[i].group = userGroup.name
    users[i].subgroup = userGroup.subgroup.find(subgroup => subgroup.id === subgroupID).pseudo;

    allUsers[users[i].id] = users[i];
}
```

You are modifying your original data though, that's not necessary a good idea.
You could create a new user in the loop and use Object.assign to avoid that.

---

Here's what I would do with only a reduce method:

```
const allUsers = users.reduce((data, user) => {
    const group = groupData.find(group => group.id === user.group);
    const name = group ? group.name : '';
    const subGroup = group ? group.subgroup.find(subgroup => subgroup.id === user.subgroup): null;
    const pseudo = subGroup ? subGroup.pseudo : '';
    data[user.group] = Object.assign({}, user, { group: name, subGroup: pseudo });
   return data;
}, {});
```

Object.assign creates a new object so it won't mutate the existing users.

Comment: how can the object assign be used in this example? and could we also replace that for loop with some mapping/filtering etc?

Comment: and what happens if a user doesnt have any group or subgroups? how can we pass  `' '` empty value? I mean the group/subgroup field doesn't exist at all.

Comment: there is a syntax error in the last line... could you please have a look at it?

Comment: this second method is outputting undefined and only returning the first user with wrong data.

Comment: is this second code piece part of the first one ? or standalone?

Comment: It should be working now, I had the wrong identifier for some stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate your user and use `array#find` to get the `group` name and `subgroup` `pseudo` name.

```js
let users = [ { "id": "123", "email": "john.doe@acme.com", "name": " John Doe", "group": "1", "subgroup": "1" }, { "id": "456", "email": "tom.hans@stk.com", "name": " Tom hans", "group": "2", "subgroup": "1" } ],
    groupData = [ { id: "1", name: "Stars",subgroup: [ { id: "1", pseudo: "big" }, { id: "2", pseudo: "small" } ] }, { id: "2", name: "Stones", subgroup: [ { id: "1", pseudo: "tiny" }, { id: "2", pseudo: "huge" } ] } ],
    result = users.reduce((r, user) => {
      var {name = '', subgroup = []} = groupData.find(o => o.id === user.group); 
      r[user.id] = Object.assign({}, user, {group: name}, {subgroup: subgroup.find(o => o.id === user.subgroup).pseudo||''});
      return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what happens if a user doesn't have `group` field? but he has subgroup... basically it means, we can't return any value, so we should return empty for both.

Comment: Just update this line `user.group && groupData.find(o => o.id === user.group);`